# Dismissin Alert in async complection Handler throws exception

Tags: xcode, ios8, swift2

I have following code which calls an async method, in its completion handler when I try to dismiss the alert it crashes.

> Assertion failure in void
>   _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(),
>   /SourceCache/UIFoundation_Sim/UIFoundation-376.14/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1547

```
    var alert1:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Data loaded", message: "all the data has been loaded", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "dismis me", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)

    mywebapi.postAsync("account/Login", token: nil, content: postData)
    {(succeeded,data:NSDictionary!)->() in

    if(succeeded)
    {
        //Crashes at below line
        alert1.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your completion handler is called on the main thread. All UI-related operations must be performed on the main thread. You can wrap the call with `dispatch_async`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    alert1.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
});
```